# Unity c: How to tell if the key of a specific int you stored as a variable has been pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my system for equipping Weapons, but I cannot figure out how to check if i has been pressed down.

```
for (int i = 0; i < gunController.Guns.Length; i++) {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(i)) {
                gunController.EquipWeapon(gunController.Guns[i]);
            }

        }
```

Comment: So what is happening when you use this code?

Comment: What variable stores the keys? There is no variable that stores any key info at this moment

Comment: I don't use Unity, but based on this
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html
you should try
if (Input.GetKeyDown(i.ToString()))

Comment: thanks chronos will try.. and btw programmer i is the variable

Comment: it WORKED!!! thank you very much

Comment: You really should look in to the [Input Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConventionalGameInput.html) to create binable names like "Weapon0" and "Weapon1" this will make it a lot easier to let users of your game rebind keys, it also makes support for gamepads easier (you can use a single `Input.GetButtonDown("Weapon0")` and it can check both the keyboard and a button on a gamepad in a single call).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Unity Docs (for Unity3D 5.4)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html), the `GetKeyDown` function of `Input` has two overloads:

1. `Input.GetKeyDown(string name)` where `name` is the name of the key being pressed
2. `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode key)` where `key` is the KeyCode enum value for the key.

*Nota bene: the second overload (`Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode key)`) is best practice.*

**Basically, there is no overload that has an** `int` **as a parameter.** `i` is an `int`.

You can fix this problem by making an array/dictionary/list (or something else) with Guns and their respective `KeyCode`s or `string`s.